# csrf token not showing input fields - Django

Tags: django, forms, csrf

I am new to django. am using `django==1.11`

am trying to create a form which inputs details of users.

my

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import loader, Template, Context, RequestContext  
from forms import UserForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.decorators import csrf

def action(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = UserForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit = False)

            return HTTPResponseRedirect('/rfid/index')
    else:
        form = UserForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('reg.html', args)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from models import UserDetails

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        fields = '__all__'
```

**reg.html**

```
{% extends "rfid/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form action = "/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <ul>

        {{ form.as_ul }}

        </ul>   

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add User">
    </form>
</div>

{% include "rfid/includes/htmlsnippet.html" %}

{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class UserDetails(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'))
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True) 
    name = models.TextField(max_length = 50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = GENDER_CHOICES)
    dob = models.DateTimeField()
    address = models.TextField(max_length = 200)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    photo_url = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

But it is only showing the submit button. Model-based fields are not displaying. I had gone through some Questions here but was not able to trace out what was the problem. can anyone help me out.

Hope all required details are given. pls, ask if I miss anything.

regards.

Comment: Csrf token is a hidden field. Do u inspect the form?

Comment: I'm not sure why this would have anything to do with the CSRF token.

Comment: does the form's html is rendered in the page source code?

Comment: change the last line in the view, `return render(request, 'reg.html', {'form':form})`

Comment: <div class="container">
 <form action = "/" method="post"><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='o6GsPYtcIKrzjZJuqgRD5Iz056bUFChaZ6QoC6lEnsLItNNRMD68Wiv2V89QKlwL' />
  <ul>
   
  

  </ul> 

  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add User">
 </form>
</div>

Comment: there is no content showing between <ul> tags. where it should have the fields

Comment: @FazilZaid no it's not working.

Comment: try to change to `render` instead of `render_to_response`

Answer (score -1):

Check out the line with `form.save(commit=False)`.
Except you want to give that line a name and later save the name like `saved_form=form.save(commit=False)` then `saved_form.safe`,  then the `commit=False` line isn't necessary. I  don't know if that is the problem, but will check and revert